# If $A \subset Z_{p}$ and $|A| < p^{2/3}$, there exist $x,y \in Z_{p}$ such that $(A+x) \cap (A+y) \cap A = \varnothing$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Let $p$ be a prime number and let $A \subset Z_{p}$ such that $|A| < p^{2/3}$. Show that there exist $x,y \in Z_{p}$ such that $(A+x) \cap (A+y) \cap A = \varnothing$ (where $(A+x)$ denotes the set $\{a+x| a \in A\}$).

I tried to use a probabilistic argument: choose at random $x,y \in Z_{p}$ independly and then try to show that 
$$P(\text{exist $a \in A$ such that $x+a \in A$ and $x+a \in A+y$}) < 1$$  By union bound this is at most the sum of $$P(\text{$x+a \in A$ and $x+a \in A+y$})$$ for each $a \in A$. Now $P(x+a \in A) = P(x \in A-a) < 1/p^{1/3}$, but I am not sure how to compute $P(x+a \in A+y)$?

Answer (score 0):

Let us fix an element $a\in A$. It belongs to $(A+x)\cap (A+y)$ for exactly
$|A|^2$ choices of pairs $(x,y)$. This is because $a\in A+x$, iff $x\in a-A$, and similarly for $y$. So to make sure that $a$ won't appear in the intersection $A\cap (A+x)\cap (A+y)$ we need to exclude $|A|^2$ choices for the pair $(x,y)$.

We can do the same for all $a\in A$. In the worst case we need to exclude a total of $|A|^3$ pairs $(x,y)$. But, as $|A|<p^{2/3}$ we have $|A|^3<p^2$. Meaning that at least one pair $(x,y)$ was not excluded by any $a$.

---

Viewed differently. Each cartesian product $(a-A)\times (a-A)$ contains $|A|^2$ elements of $\Bbb{Z}_p^2$. Therefore the union
$$
S:=\bigcup_{a\in A}(a-A)\times (a-A)\subseteq \Bbb{Z}_p^2
$$
contains at most $|A|^3<p^2$ elements. By selecting $(x,y)$ from the non-empty complement $\Bbb{Z}_p^2\setminus S$ we guarantee success.